# Why can't I comment on Facebook Questions?

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-questions

I can see a comment on a question, but I can't see how to comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Facebook Questions [FAQ](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=402#!/help/?faq=18096):

> "In order to maintain a high quality
>   of answers for questions asked, your
>   ability to comment on other people's
>   answers depends on how close you are
>   to the question asker or answerer, the
>   rating of your previous answers, and
>   whether you originally posed the
>   question."

Hope this helps!

Comment: Link is here: http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=402#!/help/?faq=18096